# Moire of lines radiating from a point an a mobile display: electric charge to magnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

[image: field lines]

This image has 300 lines radiating from a point, like an electric field.
if you view this page on a mobile, and move it, in many cases you'll see a moire pattern associated with magnetic fields: to what extent are we seeing (an analogue) how moving electric charges create magnetic fields here?

Comment: I think to no extent at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a magnetic field you're seeing, it's the general shape of a **dipole**, and in fact is more analogous to an electric dipole than a magnetic one.

When you scroll fast enough, your eye sees the image *superimposed with a moved copy of itself*. I've taken the liberty of reproducing the effect in GIMP:

[image]

As to why the field looks like a dipole, it's exactly why the field of two electric charges looks like an electric dipole: we're essentially adding together the "field lines" of two "monopole" charges (i.e. the two original images, with lines radiating outward uniformly from a central point).

Comment: Although this has nothing to do with actual specific physics, it's amazing that the human eye detects this as a dipole! For OP: this effect has nothing to do with fields of moving charges